# Configure filebeat to control how often logs are read and to ignore old logs

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I have a prospectors setup in my filebeat.yml roughly as follows:

```
filebeat.propectors:
- type: log
paths:
  - /tmp/log/typeA*.log
pipeline: "pipelineA"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
  logtype: TYPEA
- type: log
paths:
  - /tmp/log/typeB*.log
pipeline: "pipelineB"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
  logtype: TYPEB
- type: log
paths:
  - /tmp/log/typeC*.log
pipeline: "pipelineC"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
  logtype: TYPEC
```

It works fine but I need control on reading the logs. I would like to be able to control the input so that some logs are read more frequently than (e.g. for pipelineC, read only once a day, but for pipelineA, read every minute). I would also like to be able to ignore logs older than a certain age (e.g. ignore logs older than 3 days).

I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

figured this out. Here is solution:

filebeat.propectors:

```
type: log
paths:
/tmp/log/typeA*.log
ignore_older: 72h
scan_frequency: 10s
pipeline: "pipelineA"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
logtype: TYPEA
type: log
paths:
/tmp/log/typeB*.log
ignore_older: 72h
scan_frequency: 10s
pipeline: "pipelineB"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
logtype: TYPEB
type: log
paths:
/tmp/log/typeC*.log
ignore_older: 72h
scan_frequency: 10s
pipeline: "pipelineC"
fields_under_root: true
fields:
logtype: TYPEC
```